# Parse data only when specific tab is selected

Tags: codenameone

I've used Tabs in a screen. Each tab has its own json data to read. So I've used ConnectionRequest method in each tab. Hence what happened is that all connectionRequest methods run at once and the app is very slow. What I need is that the specific json data is parsed when the respective tab is selected so that only the required json is parsed. So I've used addSelectionListener so that connectionRequest for parsing json data is read only when specific tab is opened. However when the screen is read at first, the blanck screen is shown. If the tab is selected then it works. By keeping the code outside of addSelectionListener makes all the connectionRequests of each tab run at once, which I don't want. How can I solve this problem?

I need to back to a specific tab when backed from a particular screen as well. Then this issue is seen there too. ConnectionRequest doesn't run.

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
tabs.addTab("Home", calendarIcon, homeContainer);
tabs.addTab("Book", calendarIcon3, quickBookingContainer);
tabs.addTab("Servicing", calendarIcon1, servicingContainer);
tabs.addTab("History", calendarIcon2, serviceHistoryContainer);

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);

tabs.addSelectionListener((int oldSelected, int newSelected) -> {
    if (newSelected == 0) {
        //connectionRequest for parsing json data
        homeContainerRequest(homeContainer, res);
    } else if (newSelected == 1) {
        quickBookingContainerRequest(quickBookingContainer, res);
    } else if (newSelected == 2) {
        serviceRequest(serviceContainer, res);
    } else if (newSelected == 3) {
        serviceHistoryRequest(serviceHistoryContainer, res);
    } 
});


public void homeContainerRequest(Container homeContainer, Resources res){
    ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest(url, false) {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        }
    };
    con.setFailSilently(true);
    con.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
}

public void quickBookingContainerRequest(Container quickBookingContainer, Resources res){
    ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest(url1, false) {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        }
    };
    con.setFailSilently(true);
    con.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
}

public void serviceHistoryRequest(Container serviceHistoryContainer, Resources res){
    ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest(url2, false) {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        }
    };
    con.setFailSilently(true);
    con.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first tab is already selected so there's no selection event. You need to make a special case for that. Notice that tab selection happens a lot so you need to cache the results.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u. How can I make a special case for that? This problem increases when I want to show specific tab when backed from another screens. If I code outside of selection listener, the json data of all the tabs are parsed each time. eg: if I've 4 tabs, each with its own separate connectionRequest method, all 4 of them are called at once, which is the main reason I'm willing to use selection events

Comment: I don't get the problem, I think there are details about your app/design that I don't understand. I don't see why it would be a problem to invoke `homeContainerRequest` before registering the selection listener?

Comment: Lets say I am in serviceDetail screen. When the back button is pressed I need to go to tab with serivceContainer. Now the connection request for service is called. Along with it the connectionRequest for home tab is also called. Hence if homeContainerRequest is invoked before registering selection listener, two connectionRequest for home tab and service tab are called which is my main problem.

Comment: If the form already exists nothing is called. If you recreate the form you already know the tab you need to select so the logic for tab selection/event/initialization should reside also where you explicitly select the current tab...